# Orchard Blog, getting view count

Tags: module, blogs, orchardcms

I have implemented a blog with orchard and now I need to get view count of posts.
Goal is:

- get 5 top viewed post in a list
- display view count on each blog post

I have tried various solution but so fore none works, view count is always 0.

Not working for me (on 1.6)

- using voting module (no idea how to use, no docs)
  https://orchardvoting.codeplex.com/documentation
- Content view count (always 0)
  http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.ContentViewCounter
- Top views (always the same top post with 0)
  http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.galgodage.TopViews

Does anybody has successfully used or implemented this functionality?
Thanks

Edit:
I see this error in logs (no idea what module may have caused it)

```
Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager
RuntimeBinderException thrown from Action`1 by   
System.Action`1[[Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.ShapeDisplayingContext, 
Orchard.Framework, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
Can not implicitly convert type
'Orchard.Modules.Models.ModuleEntry' in 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart' 
in CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) in
Orchard.DesignerTools.Services.WidgetAlternatesFactory.
<Displaying>b__5(ShapeDisplayingContext displayedContext) in 
Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.<>c__DisplayClassc.
<Execute>b__5(Action`1 action)
```

Comment: Voting module has no inherent functionality, it is just a way for other modules to have a place to store values. Did you attach the ContentViewCounterPart to the blog post content type? And install Voting.

Comment: Voting is installed, but I have no ContentViewCounterPart in the list of parts to add...

Comment: No UserViewPart as well.

Comment: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.ContentViewCounter it should be available when you install this module

Comment: Ok, removed module and installed again. Added UserViewPart to Blog post. I then browsed site to view some post. BlogPost has Userview part, Part has a property named TotalViews... always 0. Should I need to do more than adding UserViewPart?

Comment: You shouldn't do no, I guess it isn't working then I am afraid. You could try debugging the module to find the issue and fix it yourself/contact the module author for help. He is active on Orchards codeplex forums I believe. And the error you posted looks to be caused by the Shape Tracing tool or WidgetAlternates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why the Content View Counter does not works for me.

Anyway I have managed to disable it and I have installed: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.ViewCount

This second one works, following instructions on module page.

Many thanks to Hazza for precious comments and help.

Happy Orcharding...